# Monolog wrongly rotates files as root

Tags: symfony, root, monolog, log-rotation

I use Symfony v5.4 with Monolog, which is set up (for less important logs) to do the automatic log rotating (monolog's `rotating_file` option).

The issue is that, in the production mode, on live server, when Monolog rotates such file (creates a new file for the next day), it creates the new file as a `root:root`.

All the other log files in that folder are created as `apache:apache`. Even if some log file does not already exist, and Symfony wants to auto-create it when needed, it would be created as `apache` user.

The Apache2 runs as the `apache` user, so it has no issues writing to the regular log files, but obviously when it tries writing to the new auto-rotated by Monolog, the `root:root`'s file, it fails.

I suppose that some process that is actually performing the rotation is running as a root, but - which process is that? How is this Monolog's work scheduled to be processed daily? I didn't duck-ducked any details about it.

Symfony itself is called through Apache, which runs as `apache`.

Comment: a cron task ran as a root user ?

Comment: No, there are no crontabs under root account, or at least none related to Monolog, none that I can see.
Or do you think that Monolog might have internally scheduled it with cron, and that cron process is ran as a root user?  That might be, but I'm not sure how to change that, or where to locate it.

Comment: You were right @FabienPapet, there was a separate process that was started by a cron, and it was set up to run as a root (not directly in crontab, but the command itself still had a `sudo`).  So, **sometimes** that process would run first, early in the day and automatically would create the new daily file as a `root`. Other times, Symfony would cause the file creation (before that other process), so it would be created as an `apache` user - and then there would be no failure.  That explains why was the issue  irregular as it was. If you add your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: I should also mention in here that the original "question" was actually not correct, in sense that apparently, Monolog does NOT rotate the logs, so it's not using any "tool" for the rotation. Monolog simply always tries to write to a file like `some-YYYY-MM-DD.log` - and if that file is missing, it will be created, on the fly, in the name of whichever user that ran the current process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can come from a cronjob as root or a command ran with `sudo`. This can create files if they are not existing. They have root owner, so apache can't access them.